# Angular 11 - Lazy load routing issue

Tags: angular, mean-stack, angular-lazyloading

Trying to create CRUD opration with MEAN stack. Currently using Angular 11 cli, I've created lazy module.
the lazy module has add/edit/list components. To list the data, I'm using Angular materials. The problem
what here I'm facing is that am not able to navigate to due to below error on my front end.

**Note: This may be duplicate, but I've already seen few SO solution, but unfortunatly i'm not able to fix this for more than 3 hrs.**

May be some has good eyes to point the problem what i've done here

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'students', loadChildren: () => import('./demo-app/demo-app.module').then(m => m.DemoCrudAppModule) },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

**demo-crud-app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  
  { path: '', component: ListStudentsComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'add', component: AddNewStudentsComponent },
  { path: 'view/:id', component: ViewStudentsDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'edit/:id', component: EditStudentsComponent }
];
```

when I'm trying to click mat-table data to navigate to view student details, I'm getting below console error

***ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'view/607e79ee6d81777c6ee80919'***

**View-student-details-component.html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="mat-elevation-z8 list-tbl" matSort matSortActive="firstName"
      matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="asc" *ngIf="data && data.length > 0">
      <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
                The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="_id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <a color="primary">{{ element._id }}

          </a>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <!-- Position Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Student Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.firstName }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Age</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.age }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Weight Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.status }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns" [routerLink]="['/view/', row._id]"></tr>
    </table>
```

**my local url - http://localhost:4200/students**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a html and clicking function in ts of ListStudentsComponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your routerLink to

```html
[routerLink]="['view', row._id]"
```

If current active URL is `/students` then clicking on `tr` will navigate to `http://localhost:4200/students/view/607e79ee6d81777c6ee80919`

If you add `/` before path like `['/view/', row._id]` then URL will navigate to `http://localhost:4200/view/607e79ee6d81777c6ee80919` no matter what current active URL is.

Comment: need one help, same issue am facing when i click on back button to navigate from view page to list page

Comment: @Mr.Learner Try `routerLink="/students"` to go back to the list page